# Editing files locally with Vagrant

Tags: vim, text-editors, editing, vagrant, nano

Is it possible to edit files using non command-line editors, such as Notepad++, with Vagrant? 
If so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If your editor can do that, it is possible to edit code on your box via SSH:

- `:e scp://user@host//some/directory/` in [G]Vim,
- use the built-in SSH plugin in Notepad++.

But your box uses the directory where you issued `$ vagrant up` as a shared directory: put your files there and you'll we be able to access them with CLI editors from your box and with your host's GUI editors.

Comment: So I would have to move every file back and forth with every edit?

Comment: No, that directory is where you put your project and where you work.